# Pyinstaller fails with pyscard on windows

Tags: python-3.x, swig, pyinstaller, pyscard

I am trying to use pyinstaller on a simple script which use pyscard.

```
from smartcard.Exceptions import NoCardException
from smartcard.System import readers
from smartcard.util import toHexString

for reader in readers():
    try:
        connection = reader.createConnection()
        connection.connect()
        print(reader, toHexString(connection.getATR()))
    except NoCardException:
        print(reader, 'no card inserted')
```

This is OK on Ubuntu but fails on Windows7 and Windows10 machines. 
The failure is the same on both versions of windows, here is the screen output on Windows7:

```
C:\Users\seb\ownCloud\rex>pyinstaller --clean --win-private-assemblies --hidden-import=smartcard.scard._scard --onefile testpyscard.py
55 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.3.1
55 INFO: Python: 3.6.5
56 INFO: Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
57 INFO: wrote C:\Users\seb\ownCloud\rex\testpyscard.spec
60 INFO: UPX is not available.
60 INFO: Removing temporary files and cleaning cache in C:\Users\seb\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller
74 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\seb\\ownCloud\\rex', 'C:\\Users\\seb\\ownCloud\\rex']
75 INFO: checking Analysis
76 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
76 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
79 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
81 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
2472 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'smartcard.scard._scard'
2564 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
2566 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Python36\python.exe
3106 INFO: Caching module hooks...
3111 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\seb\ownCloud\rex\testpyscard.py
3115 INFO: Loading module hooks...
3115 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
3195 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
3196 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
3382 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
3383 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
3388 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
3461 INFO: Looking for eggs
3461 INFO: Using Python library C:\Python36\python36.dll
3462 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
3465 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\seb\ownCloud\rex\build\testpyscard\warntestpyscard.txt
3501 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\seb\ownCloud\rex\build\testpyscard\xref-testpyscard.html
3506 INFO: checking PYZ
3507 INFO: Building PYZ because out00-PYZ.toc is non existent
3507 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\seb\ownCloud\rex\build\testpyscard\out00-PYZ.pyz
3910 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\seb\ownCloud\rex\build\testpyscard\out00-PYZ.pyz completed successfully.
3914 INFO: checking PKG
3914 INFO: Building PKG because out00-PKG.toc is non existent
3915 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
3929 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\seb\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\python36.dll
3930 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
4036 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\seb\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\_ssl.pyd
4036 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
4047 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\seb\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\unicodedata.pyd
4048 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
4055 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\seb\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\pyexpat.pyd
4056 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
4066 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\seb\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\_hashlib.pyd
4066 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
4075 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\seb\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\select.pyd
4076 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
4083 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\seb\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\_bz2.pyd
4083 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
4089 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\seb\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\_lzma.pyd
4089 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
4095 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\seb\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\_socket.pyd
4095 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
4100 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\seb\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\_scard.pyd
4100 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
5488 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg completed successfully.
5490 INFO: Bootloader C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
5491 INFO: checking EXE
5491 INFO: Building EXE because out00-EXE.toc is non existent
5492 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
5493 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\seb\ownCloud\rex\dist\testpyscard.exe
5499 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc completed successfully.

C:\Users\seb\ownCloud\rex>.\dist\testpyscard.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testpyscard.py", line 28, in <module>
    from smartcard.Exceptions import NoCardException
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\smartcard\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\smartcard\System.py", line 28, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\smartcard\reader\ReaderFactory.py", line 34, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\smartcard\pcsc\PCSCReader.py", line 28, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\smartcard\pcsc\PCSCContext.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\smartcard\scard\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\smartcard\scard\scard.py", line 119, in <module>
  File "site-packages\smartcard\scard\scard.py", line 118, in swig_import_helper
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'smartcard.scard._scard'
[7924] Failed to execute script testpyscard
```

Note: The optional arguments to pyinstaller do not make any difference, I tried the 8 combinations with and without --onefile, --hidden-import and --win-private-assemblies. On ubuntu pyinstaller was invoked simply with the name of the script and --onefile.

Note 2: I had the same issue with Python3.6-32 on the Windows7 machine. I uninstalled all the python stuff I could find on the machine and made a fresh install of Python3.6 x86-64 and the matching pyscard (using dist\pyscard-1.9.6.win-amd64-py3.6.msi from https://ci.appveyor.com/project/LudovicRousseau/pyscard)

Any help to understand or fix the issue would be greatly appreciated, I don't even know if the problem is related to my setup or Pyinstaller or Pyscard :-S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue on Windows 7 and Windows 10. I think the problems occurs because of the runtime import in the **swig_import_helper** function in *scard.py*. So I have added following to my PyInstaller options:

```
--add-data "path_to_python\\Python36-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\smartcard\\scard\\_scard.cp36-win32.pyd;.\\smartcard\\scard\\"
```

This fixed the problem for me both under Windows 7 and Windows 10.

My testing environment:

- Windows 7 64 bit
- Python 3.6 32 bit
- pyscard 1.9.7
- PyInstaller 3.3.1

Comment: works also with python 3.6 64bit, just change filename to _scard.cp36-win_amd64.pyd. Thanks :-)